# Using while condition for age restriction

Tags: string, conditional-statements, integer

```
while True:
age = (input("Please enter your age: ").lower())
if age == "":
    print("Your age cannot be blank.")
elif age.isalpha():
    print("Sorry I did not understand that.")
elif age <= "17":
    print("You must be above 18 years of age to play the game.")
    quit()
else:
    break
```

Whenever I tried running the 3rd condition, it doesnt satisfy the condition whenever I type only a single digit number.

But starting from digit 10 and above, it does satisfy the condition.

How can I correct this?

Comment: The string `"17"` is less than the string `"2"` in alphabetical order. You should convert those ages into ints prior to comparing them.